# MVC, Passing count of 3 tables to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to pass the counts of three different tables into a view along with a list of albums. It's a mod of the MvcMusicStore tutorial. I'm getting the "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used..." error. I understand that it has to do with lazy loading, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

```
// Controller
public class StoreManagerController : Controller
{
    private MusicStoreDBEntities context = new MusicStoreDBEntities();  

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // counts
        ViewData["artistCount"] = context.Artists
                                     .Select(e => new { e.ArtistId }).Count();
        ViewData["genreCount"] = context.Genres
                                     .Select(e => new { e.GenreId }).Count();
        ViewData["albumCount"] = context.Albums
                                     .Select(e => new { e.AlbumId }).Count();

        // also tried two other ways...same result. 
        //ViewData["artistCount"] = context.Artists
                                 .Select(e => new { e.ArtistId }).ToList().Count;
        //ViewData["artistCount"] = context.Artists
                                 .Select(e => new { e.ArtistId }).ToList().Count();

        // album list
        var albums = context.Albums.Include(a => a.Genre).Include(a => a.Artist);
        return View(albums.ToList());
    }
}


// View - Index.cshtml  
@model IEnumerable<MVC_App1.Models.Album>
<div>
<label><strong>Database Counts:</strong></label>
    Albums: @ViewData["albumCount"] ...
    Artists: @ViewData["artistCount"]  ...
    Genres: @ViewData["genreCount"]
</div>  

<table>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Artist.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AlbumArtUrl)
    </td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

SOLUTION:

So I went with the suggestion to add a new model.

```
public class AlbumsCollection 
{
    public IEnumerable<Album> Albums = new List<Album>();
    public IEnumerable<Artist> Artists = new List<Artist>();
    public IEnumerable<Genre> Genres = new List<Genre>();
}
```

And then do the counts in the view. I realized that I m passing the whole Album list to the view anyway, so it isn't a slowdown there. And For the Artists and Genres...there won't be many anyway, as they are 1-to-many relationships. I guess that's giving up on doing the Counts in the controller....but I guess this is good enough.

Comment: I'm surprised using ToList doesn't work. Are you sure you've tried.ToList.Count()? That effectively runs the query and returns it to an in-memory List. Store the results in an enumerable before you store it in ViewData.. and step through your code to make sure it's actually storing it properly.

Comment: Surprised me to. I just double-checked doing it that way, same error.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a new Model:

```
public class AlbumsCollection
{
    public IEnumerable<Album> Albums = new List<Album>();

    //Popular albums 
    //Newest albums 
    //etc
}

public class Album
{
    public int ArtistID;
    public int GenreId;
    public int AlbumId;
}
```

Populate that Model in the Controller:

```
public class StoreManagerController : Controller
{
    private MusicStoreDBEntities context = new MusicStoreDBEntities();  

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        AlbumsCollection albumsCollection = new AlbumsCollection();

        albumsCollection.Albums = context.Albums;

        return View(albumsCollection);
    }
}
```

Then you could just use this in your view:

```
@model Models.AlbumsCollection
<div>
<label><strong>Database Counts:</strong></label>
    Albums: @Model.Albums.Count ...
    Artists: @Model.Albums.Count(album => album.ArtistID != -1)  ...
    Genres: @Model.Albums.Count(album => album.GenreID != -1)
</div>  

<table>
@foreach (var item in Model.Albums) {
<tr>
    <td>
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Artist.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AlbumArtUrl)
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

(Assuming that Genre and Artist are ID's)

Comment: I considered that...but I thought it would be bad to pass the whole collection of things to the view and Counting them there. Seems like it would be more than I need. Is it possible to get the Count in the controller, and pass that number to the view?

Comment: Yea instead of having a collection of albums in the Model I suggested just add three variable ints as counts. Then in the controller set those. Then in the view access them with Model.ArtistCount and No initializing the context in the Controller Index function doesn't matter.

Comment: As for your Error I believe the context isn't being initialized? MVC should initialize if for you at the beginning of your Index put context.Albums.ToList();

Comment: Not quite there. All the counts are always the same number. <br/>Database Counts: Albums: 3 ... Artists: 3 ... Genres: 3.  Let me try specifying 3 ints in the model, instead of doing your  @Model.Albums.Count(album => album.ArtistID != -1)

Comment: No, I used a new Model which contained int AlbumCount, etc...but when I try to set those in the controller, same error.    albumsCollection.ArtistCount = context.Artists.Select(e => new { e.ArtistId }).Count();

Comment: So @Model.Albums.Count(album => album.ArtistID != -1) was closer...but I understand why the count will always be the same. Each album entry has an Artist =! -1. So I get the count of Albums each time, not the count of artists in the Artists table, which has a 1-to-many relationship to the Albums.

Comment: I would think that my initial approach of multiple queries and putting each into ViewData["xxxCount"] would have worked.  But it seems it doesn't like multiple Selects in the same ActionResult method.

Comment: Yes if you wanted to get a count of all the Artists you'd have to access the Artists collection however you store it in your DB I'm not sure. Good luck to you hope I've helped.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `MusicStoreDBEntities context = new MusicStoreDBEntities();`  inside the Index action

Comment: No, that didn't work. Same "ObjectContext instance has been disposed..."